# Hidden Markov Parameters

Tags: r, hmmlearn

I am making a Hidden Markov Model for a maternity dataset in R. Lets say I want to observe the patterns in 1st, 2nd and 3rd pregnancy. In every pregnancy, I have two variables i.e Son and Daughter. But my model is taking Son and daughter as states while I want Preg 1,2 and 3 as three different states. Data looks like this;

```
P1   P2   P3 
S    D     S 
D    D     S 
S    S     D 
S    S     S
```

How can tailor my model in this way?

Comment: Are you using an external package? Please make the question more clear.

Comment: After seeing your questions record I have deleted my answer. I believe that it's obvious that you are trying to use a concept *before* learning it. Please don't do that, read what it is about (there are many online sources) and the packages' docs.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I am using packages like "seqHMM", "HMM" and "Traminer". Meanwhile I am also reading different PDFz available for these packages.

Comment: @RuiBarradas thanks for your advice, I am reading about this topic too.